# PHP Chart Library Solution

Tags: php, kohana, charts

Good day.

I am a newbie to PHP framework, and I know a little about CI. 
Recently, i plan to start my new practice project with Kohana.
I am looking for a good PHP Chart Solution.

Requirement:
Free chart library is better;
Integrated with Kohana well.

Could you give me suggestion about it.

Thank you for your reply here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

open flash charts is one (http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/)

xml/swf charts (http://www.maani.us/xml_charts/) and amcharts (amcharts.com) both have free versions.

Answer (score 4):

Adding [EZ Graph](http://ezcomponents.org/docs/api/latest/introduction_Graph.html) to the list

Answer (score 4):

I would vote for [phpChart](http://phpchart.net). Very easy to use. It's PHP based, the rendering occurs on the client side with rich charting feature support such as pie, 3d, bubble etc.

Answer (score 3):

Meet [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/).

Not really PHP solution because it's javascript. But people have been using it as front-end with PHP as the back-end for so long.

My own Kohana module that uses Flot: http://www.nusantarasoftware.com/hitlogger

Comment: Hello Lukman, Does Flot could interactive with a lot of DB Data? I plan to creat my chart from the DB database. thank you. I found some sample demo example from Flot link URL above.

Comment: btw. Does Flot support 3D chart? i doesn't find 3D sample from the URL link above. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

http://pchart.sourceforge.net/

Free charting library

**Unfortunately it is not integrated with Kohala**

Answer (score 2):

http://sparkline.org/

It is worth digging through the excellent collection here (Flash, JS, PHP, etc.):

http://www.webappers.com/category/components/charts/

Being a mootooler I always prefer Mootools Javascript charts:

- http://blog.greghoustondesign.com/canvas-pie-chart-with-tooltips/
- http://highcharts.com/
- http://moochart.coneri.se/
- http://www.copix.org/index.php/wiki/Mootools/Charts/en

Comment: i never learn mootooler before. but i would like to learn it at my practice project. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [PHPlot](http://phplot.sourceforge.net/) with good results.

I'm not aware of a Kohana integration, but I just made a very simple charts controller to generate the charts and that works well.

Comment: +1 Hi Sam, I just downloaded and tested the PHPlot sample(simpleplot.html /.php) at my localhost. It's lightweight and cool. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There's a Kohana Charts module based on Google Charts:

https://github.com/ae0000/kohana-charts

Answer (score 0):

It's not strictly PHP, since it uses [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) to render the graphs on the client side, but I recently developed a small [graphing library](http://www.binpress.com/app/analytics-and-graphing-with-php-sql/851) for fetching database data, process it with PHP and create Google Analytics style interactive graphs from it.

It's basically a complete server/client solution to turning your database tables into graphs, and should be easy to integrate with Kohana (I've used it a lot with the Zend Framework).