# Using PHP to create a graphing class

Tags: php, css, class, graph

Part of the school programming project I have chosen to undertake requires generating a bar graph using PHP, based on users data. My teacher has made it clear that I mustn't use an open source class or anybody else's code. He has also forbidden me from using CSS to display the graph, partly claiming it's not possible (I have seen ways online).

I had a brief look at some popular PHP graphing classes such as Jpchart and Pchart and they all looked fairly complicated, with tens of thousands of lines of code.

Surely having to write a class to generate the jpeg must also be rather complicated.

Does anybody have any suggestions, or should I put my foot down and tell him these expectations are unrealistic?

Comment: Yes, tell him his expectations are unrealistic and he is suffering from NIH syndrome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Chart Library Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935330/php-chart-library-solution)

Comment: Not really. This other guy is asking for pre-written code. I'm wondering whether it's feasible to do without pre-written code. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Not using CSS? Fair enough if that's the criteria he wants. But claiming it's not possible?? *Really*? Sounds like your teacher needs some teaching.

Answer (score 1):

His opinions on CSS are wrong, and have been wrong since the day CSS was invented, if we're just talking about a simple bar chart. It is trivial to create a bar chart using a few `<div>` tags and a small amount of CSS.

He's probably fishing for specific solutions that he understands -- maybe an HTML table? (I really hope not) Or maybe generating an image using the GD library in PHP.

If I were you, I'd pick an unusual solution like SVG to do it. Generate the chart in SVG, and output it to the browser. Meets his criteria, but without using any of his "forbidden" options. (but note - make sure your teacher uses a browser that supports SVG [ie newer than IE8] before taking this option!)

Answer (score 0):

It's not that hard. Look at the image functions in php. [gd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [image magick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).

Especially the [rectangle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledrectangle.php) function would be interesting for you.

Answer (score 0):

Forbidding you from using CSS is a total dick move on his part. Short of getting into using GDlib functions [which I'm assuming isn't the point of the exercise] you could create a 1x2 cell table and set the cell widths according to the bar value, but it will be somewhat of a pain *without* CSS. To avoid the ire of Professor Dickbag you'll be stuck setting HTML attributes on everything.

Your instructor is *flat-out **wrong*** about this not being possible with CSS.

If he's just an angry old neckbeard he probably wants something like this:

```
Tom:   |****      | 43%
Dick:  |***       | 27%
Harry: |********  | 82%
```

So it's just like being back in 1981 on some DEC PDP-whatever.

### edit

Since your instructor stipulated that he wants the graph in the form of an *image*, you will want to use the [GD library functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php). The example code in the doc page for [`imagefilledrectangle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledrectangle.php) should be more than enough to get you started:

```
<?php
// Create a 55x30 image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(55, 30);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

// Draw a white rectangle
imagefilledrectangle($im, 4, 4, 50, 25, $white);

// Save the image
imagepng($im, './imagefilledrectangle.png');
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: Oh... and no HTML either.

Comment: @Sam ...really? 90%+ probability of 'angry neckbeard' mentioned in the edit I just made.

Comment: Haha. He's made it clear that it has to be an "image". I think he actually wants me to generate the jpeg. It's my first year programming and he's expecting me to do what has been done by a large group of professional programmers over a long period of time.

Comment: @Sam you seriously need to clarify in your question that you need to generate an *image* of a bar graph. FYI: in *my* first year programming course we did similar exercises in a very early version of Java which was much less friendly than using [PHP GD functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledrectangle.php). Just because something's been done before and better by someone else doesn't mean it's not a useful learning exercise.

Comment: The exercise isn't one he has set me. It's for my coursework. I chose to have some sort of graphing functionality. He has never used PHP or anything more complicated than Pascal and Basic, for that matter. He just makes up stuff as we go along.

Comment: Sorry, looking back at my previous comment, I think I've misled you. He didn't actually say It has to be an image. He's just under the impression that it's the only way.

Answer (score 0):

charting via html/css is totally possible.

let's say your making a bar chart. start by doing your calculations for min + max and defining a height for both. after that take all your other values and decide what their heights will be (some percentage of your min/max). after that you have two choices in my mind. 1, render your html as tables w/ cells and explicilty given their heights/widths. or render a bunch of divs with ids and classes then create your css on the fly (either inline with the style attribute or just write the css into the script tag dynamically) and in your css set the heights based on what you decided earlier.

here's [some code](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/drawing-divs/) using the D3js library.
this methodology is quite sound, just do your code in a similar manner using php not js.

if you want to look at some other examples: [here are some examples](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/data-visualization-with-css-graphs-charts-and-more/) of html/css charts. [pcharts](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/) is a great library that uses the GD php extension to generate chart images in jpg/png format. if your planning on generating images on the fly, this library should provide some good inspiration.

**UPDATE**
i couldn't help but make a php/css example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .bar {
            background: #660000;
            color: #fff;
            height: 20px;
            width: auto;
            min-width: 2px;
            clear: both;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php

    //array of values
    $vals = array(
        'git' => 9001, 
        'svn' => 4213, 
        'bitkeeper' => 7391,
        'mercurial' => 2114,
        'cvs' => 806, 
    );
    //minimim and maximum
    $min = 1;
    $max = 200;

    //calculate scale, draw, and loop
    foreach ($vals as $key => $val) {
        $scale = (2 * ($val-$min)/($max-$min))*8;
        echo('<div class="bar" style="width: '.$scale.'px" title="'.$key.' = '.$val.'">'.$key."</div>");
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple once you break it down to the basic tasks. Think back to how you were originally taught at school on how to do a graph:

- You start with the size of the graph (i.e. the paper size)
- You know how many bars you need to draw so you can work out the space each one requires
- You know the maximum and minimum values in your data, so it's easy to work out scales

The rest is just keys and title!